# Why does a ViewController not declare when it contains a NavigationController when pushing a segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue

I just want to have a segue pass something to my SecondViewController but it 'isn't there' in my code. I get an error "use of unidentified identifier SecondViewController", but I have imported it's corresponding .h file. 
I have tried a few different combinations of trying to explicitly declare it, but nothing is working. 
What is the correct way to do this - what am I missing!
My SecondViewController has a NavigationControllerEmbedded so the segue from the FirstViewController to the SecondViewController is seeming awfully difficult for a relatively simple process.

*Code:*
**FirstViewController.h**

```
(Should there be something here?)
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h" 

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"123"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
        SecondViewController *BVC = (SecondViewController *)([navController viewControllers][0]);
```

I am getting the error at the above line.

```
BVC.ATitle = @"SomeText"
BVC.AImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomePicture.jpg"];
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ALabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *AImageView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *AImg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ATitle;
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h" 

@implementation ButtonViewController
@synthesize ALabel;
@synthesize AImageView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.ALabel.text = self.ATitle;
    self.AImageView.image = self.AImg;
}
```

Edit: But am I missing blatantly missing a declaration of the secondViewController anywhere in my code, otherwise why else would it not even be in the prompt when I begin to try and type it. Even if I try it without the NavController all together, it still gives the unidentified identifer error.

Comment: Is your first view controller embedded in the navigation controller? Or only the second?

Comment: @Paulw11 No the first view controller is not, only the second.

Comment: Then I don't think you can use a push segue from 1 to 2, but regardless you should set a breakpoint in prepareForSegue and examine navController to see what sort of object it is. I suspect you may find it is a reference to a SecondViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `navigationController.topViewController` instead of `navigationController.viewControllers[0]`.

Try deleting the second view controller files from Xcode (without moving them to the Trash) and then re-adding them. Also, clean the project before compiling again.

Another problem with your code is that you are not following the convention of using variable names in camelCase starting with a small letter. While this should not matter for compiling, it does make your code less readable.

Comment: instead of what exactly?

Comment: I spelled it out - sorry I thought it was obvious. It should also solve the question (as the problem is likely with the casting).

Comment: @Mundi Yay! Removing and readding fixed it. Probably should have tried that earlier. New it would have been simple. Still, why would that just randomly happen?